# How to Close activity ( Still_Image_Camera intent ) in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm developing a app, it works "when i take 2 photos with continously, camera will close"

so i launch the camera with "MediaStore.IntentActionStillImageCamera"
and it can take photo continuously.

and with Fileobserver, i can count How much photo was took.

The last is i have to close camera automatically with no action when condition is true.
but, i tried process.kill, activity.finishactivity....
all failed..

How can I close camera app automatically? in Android 9.0

--code modified ----

all code is in Xamarin.Forms in Application.Android

```
// MainActivity.cs ( common code is removed )
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Instance = this;
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}

//OtherClass.cs ( i launch camera app with intent )
public void TakePictureAsync()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.IntentActionStillImageCamera);
    MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
//OtherClass.cs ( close activity )

public void ExitActivity()
{
    MainActivity.Instance.FinishActivity(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
activity.FinishActivity(0);
```

try to change it to :

```
MainActivity.Instance.FinishActivity(0);
```

I simulated your scene with a delay, and it worked:

in page.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage: ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IStartAndCloseCamera>().Open();
    }
}
```

interface **IStartAndCloseCamera.cs** :

```
public interface IStartAndCloseCamera
{
    void Open();
}
```

in Android poject **AndroidStartAndCloseCamera.cs**:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AndroidStartAndCloseCamera))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  private int sec = 20;
  System.Threading.Timer _dispatcherTimer;
  class AndroidStartAndCloseCamera : IStartAndCloseCamera
    {
      public void Open()
       {
        TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(Tick);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.IntentActionStillImageCamera);
        MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(intent1, 0);
        _dispatcherTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, null, 0, 1000);
        return true;
       }

    private void Tick(object state)
    {          
       MainActivity.Instance.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            if (sec > 0)
            {
                sec--;
            }
            else
            {
                _dispatcherTimer.Dispose();
                MainActivity.Instance.FinishActivity(0);

            }
        });

    }
   }
}
```

Comment: @이정원 are all the codes you show above in your MainActivity ?

Comment: @이정원 let's talk [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198813/talk)

Comment: i'm less than 20 reputation, so i can't talk :(

Comment: @이정원 ok,where do you call ExitActivity method ?in your OtherClass.cs ?

Comment: ExitActivity called from MainPage.xaml.cs in button, entire progress is 1. start MainPage.Xaml  2. when i clicked button, StartActivity(Still_IMAGE_CAMERA), 3. when i take a photo, count photo with fileobserver 4. when condition is true in fileobserver, Call ExitActivity

Comment: @이정원 so you  use DependencyService  in your MainPage.xam.cs ?

Comment: yes, i used dependencyservice, and it is otherClass.cs

Comment: @이정원 Is the count normal? Successful entry into the ExitActivity method?

Comment: when i call "Console.WriteLine("Something")",if condition true ( take a photo count > 1 ),  it works well.

Comment: @이정원 it's strange,it works well for me when i do with delay,i post the code,and you could hava a look.

Comment: it still not working, could you bring me all code? i guess i'm testing app in samsung m20 and the samsung camera app is problem.

Comment: not working with dispatchertimer and trying RunOnUiThread now

Comment: RunOnUiThread is not working, i'm trying to test with other device

Comment: @이정원 ok,when you use timer with a delay,it still not work ?

Comment: in Samsung m20, i use other camera app  instead samsung native camera app, and it works well. the camera app was problem! thank you

Comment: @이정원 i feel Samsung customizations often have unspeakable problems

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 2 alternatives way:

1. Set `finish();` with use of current context
2. Set `setResult(Activity.RESULT.CANCELLED);`

Comment: i tried it,  Main app is finished, but camera is still working. so when i close the camera, mainapp is initalized